# Whats wrong with this MySQL function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've seen this function in this link:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    -- max strlen=255
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
          SET c = c + 1;
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
          END IF;
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
            IF c > c_temp THEN 
              SET c = c_temp; 
            END IF;
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
  END;
```

But when I try to execute i'm getting this error message:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

MySQL version: 5.1.53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiters!

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
  ...
  ...
  ...
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```